Ansible_runner - provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
I am trying to setup Ansible to run with python, but cannot get the config files right. I haven't setup an inventory file before.
Python:
r = ansible_runner.run(
    private_data_dir="/home/me/path/ansible",
    playbook=playbook,
)

Contents of /home/me/path/ansible/:
ansible.cfg:
[default]
private_key_file = "/home/path_to_key/key"
inventory = "/home/me/path/ansible/hosts"

hosts.ini
[default]
1.2.3.4 

I have tried specifying the full path, only the filename, specifying the file extension, adding ansible_host= etc, but I always end up with the error:
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

Playbook:
---
- name: Test
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_host_key_checking: false
  remote_user: admin_user
  become: true

There are so many formats that I am struggling to see where I am going wrong.
ansible-inventory -i hosts.ini --list
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /home/me/path/ansible/hosts.ini with ini plugin: /home/me/path/ansible/hosts.ini:2: Expected
key=value host variable assignment, got: 1.2.3.4

The example code just shows an IP, and I have tried ansible_host=1.2.3.4. I don't know what key=value it is after.

I was missing:
[inventory]
enable_plugins = yaml, ini

from ansible.cfg
I also did need to specify hosts.ini and remove the quotes again.
